# Ruby instance variable correct syntax highlighting in sublime

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3

I am using "Spacegrey Eighties" theme with "Monokai - Spacegray" UI color scheme. I'm also using packages "Ruby" and "SublimeLinter-ruby" ...

I'd like to see the `@` the same color as the rest of the instance variable. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://ilkinulas.github.io/programming/2016/02/05/sublime-text-syntax-highlighting.html . You could set a regex that matches for `@`, E.g. `^@`

Comment: Is the `Ruby` package you're using the one that ships with Sublime? If so, a color scheme tweak should probably be enough, I think.

Comment: I tried a bunch of color schemes. Know a good one?